# Android ActionBar setCheckable() not working

Tags: android, checkbox, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make one of the `MenuItems` on my `Menu` have a checkmark ability, but it doesn't seem to work. All other `MenuItems` are working, this one does too, except for the checkmark display. What am I doing wrong?

```
MenuItem actionPickMode = menu.add(0, 3, 0, "pickmode");
actionPickMode.setTitle("Pick Mode");
actionPickMode.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
actionPickMode.setVisible(true);
actionPickMode.setCheckable(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to add a checkmark to a `MenuItem` that is actually on the Action Bar. According to this question it isn't possible: [Android action bar checkable menu item does not work/show properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148746/android-action-bar-checkable-menu-item-does-not-work-show-properly)

What you can do is implement it yourself--when the item is clicked, use `setIcon` to change the drawable, and maintain the state of the toggle yourself. This question describes how you can get the built-in checkmark `Drawable`s: [How to access checkmark drawable in Android OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260049/how-to-access-checkmark-drawable-in-android-os)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom layout for your action containing a checkbox. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148746/android-action-bar-checkable-menu-item-does-not-work-show-properly/30894754#30894754).