# Checkbox in menu Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, checkbox, android-mediaplayer

I am new into Android programming. I am currently integrating media player in my app. Via the menu, I want the user to turn off the sound, but also start it again if desired. Right now I have a checkbox that is checked when the music is played and the music to be shut off when not checked.

I have managed to insert checkbox in the menu and got it to be checked when the app starts, just as it should. But when I try to uncheck it, the app shuts down ...

Anyone have publisher? See obvious errors? Or just want to give tips?

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        //Switch-sats i syfte om att det kommer tillkomma fler alternativ
        //Switchen bygger på att hämta rätt id ifrån användarens val
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_help:
                //Bytar Activity till help
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, help.class);
                startActivity(intent);          
            return true;

        case R.id.music:
            final CheckBox music = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.music);
            music.setChecked(true);
            music.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    backsound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity1.this, R.raw.backsound);  
                    backsound.start();
                    backsound.setLooping(true);
                }else{
                    music.setChecked(false);
                    backsound.stop();
                }
            }});

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }}}
```

**Main_activity.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/help"/>

<item
     android:id="@+id/music" 
     android:title="@string/musik" 
     android:checkable="true"
     android:checked="true" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148746/android-action-bar-checkable-menu-item-does-not-work-show-properly/8493609#8493609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <PreferenceCategory
           android:summary="@string/summary_category"
           android:title="@string/title_category">
           <CheckBoxPreference
                 android:key="main"
                 android:defaultValue="true"
                 android:summary="@string/summary_main"
                 android:title="@string/title_main" 
          />
                  </PreferenceCategory>
<!--Any other categories include here-->
</PreferenceScreen>
```

You can do this simply by setting `android:dependancy` to the key of the check box in which the respective check boxes must depend on.

Now create a folder named xml in res folder and put your preferences xml file inside that. 
Then do the following.

```
 public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


    }

}
```

You can also do this with fragments which is more recommended. But the above method is much more easy. If you want to do that with fragments, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) which contains everything you need to know about creating a Settings Activity.

> Hope this helps!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The folowing codec will cause the app shuts down ...

```
final CheckBox music = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.music);
music.setChecked(true);
```

instead, you can do this:

```
item.setChecked(true)
```