# How to check if the checkbox is selected or not in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-menu

I am using following code to add `checkbox` in `Android Action Bar`:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_checkbox"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
    android:title="@string/action_check"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

How can I get the value of above `checkbox` whether it is selected or not as `Menu item` in android?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `isChecked()` to get the checked state of a `CheckBox`:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.action_checkbox);

if(checkBox.isChecked())
   // do something
else 
   // do something else
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but where in onOptionsItemSelected ?

Comment: If you are asking about where to use this code, then you can use it anywhere u want, as the `findViewById()` will work in any context.

Comment: It's an Action bar Menu Item. So, It will not work anywhere :)

Comment: From my knowledge the `findViewById()` can get a view from anywhere, as it gets views from the `R` file which is pretty much accessible from all contexts in your application.

Answer (score 3):

your java code where you manage `checkbox` click event

```
 @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       MenuItem check = menu.findItem(R.id.action_checkbox);
       CheckBox c_box =(CheckBox) check.getActionView();
       c_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "checked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "unchecked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
      return true;
   }
```

your menu looks like ok

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_checkbox"
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
android:title="@string/action_check"
app:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

Hope it works.. let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: I am getting an exception i.e. `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.LinearLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: at `CheckBox c =(CheckBox)rl_viewBag.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    `

Comment: is it fragment or activity where you use this method ?

Comment: did you check  rl_viewBag it is null or has a reference

Comment: I copied your whole above code and paste it as it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93327/discussion-between-tanim-reja-and-def).

Answer (score -1):

Please Refer to [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) for simple questions like these.

Also onOptionsItemSelected is part of Menu.

Comment: Even then refer to the documentation. Don't waste people's time if you have't done research. SO is for problems not to teach.

Comment: Ah! Never mind guys :)

@SnowTauren Actually you also didn't search it on official doc because there is no information available about "How to use checkboxes in menu_item" and "What is the problem with it"? "Why these checkboxes are not showing up on App bar". did you?

But that's ok :)

Comment: @Def I think you should try google first :) But it's ok Please refer this question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148746/android-action-bar-checkable-menu-item-does-not-work-show-properly

Comment: @AmitPal I know these comments are old. But this simple question is good for future people. Anyone looking for this will find the SO question (like me) and see the answer faster than looking through the documentation