# onOptionsItemSelected is not working in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-checkbox

I have a `menu_item` and here is the code:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
    android:title="In Stocks"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_checkbox"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
    android:title="@string/action_check"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

I am trying to catch `Menu_item_clicked_event` So, I write following code in `Activity` file

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_checkbox:
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_search:
            System.out.println("xas");
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I am pressing the `action_search` it's working but not for `action_checkbox`. Why this is happening? I am getting No exception in `ADB logs`. Is this is the right way to do check for `Checkboxes`?

Comment: Did you try android.R.id.action_checkbox: ? instead of just R.id.action_checkbox

Comment: Throwing an error "cannot resolve action_checkbox".

Comment: Ok, what of this  if ( ((CheckBox)item).isChecked() ) {   //  }

Comment: debug point is not even hitting the `switch (id)`. So, it doesn't matter what inside it is (If I am not wrong here)

Comment: Looks like bug in android. I have moved Checkbox in overflow menu and it works.

Answer (score 0):

app:actionViewClass should be android:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_checkbox"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
        android:icon="@drawable/unchecked"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:title="@string/action_check"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
```

However checkbox will not be visble. [Referthis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148746/android-action-bar-checkable-menu-item-does-not-work-show-properly)

you could have your own icon and set it android:icon=

And in class

```
case R.id.action_checkbox:
        if(item.isChecked()){
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.unchecked);
        }
        else {
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.checked);
        }
    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
break;
```

Comment: That means I need to replace the icon with selected checkbox when user click on it