# How to Create Selectable Headers in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigationview

In my application, I am programmatically populating my `NavigationView` menu with something like

```
val menu = navigation.menu
menu.setGroupCheckable(MENU_GROUP, true, true)
val subMenu = menu.addSubMenu(MENU_GROUP, 0, 0, "New group")

subMenu.add(0, 0, 0, "item 1").apply { isCheckable = true }
subMenu.add(0, 1, 1, "item 2").apply { isCheckable = true }
subMenu.add(0, 2, 2, "item 3").apply { isCheckable = true }
subMenu.add(0, 3, 3, "item 4").apply { isCheckable = true }

val subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu(MENU_GROUP, 1, 1, "New group 2")
subMenu1.add(1, 0, 0, "item 1").apply { isCheckable = true }
subMenu1.add(1, 1, 1, "item 2").apply { isCheckable = true }
subMenu1.add(1, 2, 2, "item 3").apply { isCheckable = true }
subMenu1.add(1, 3, 3, "item 4").apply { isCheckable = true }
```

This allows me to get any of those "item *" `MenuItem`s to be selectable but I am not able to select any of the `SubMenu` headers.

[image: Here is a visual explanation]

[According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8493609/1572848),

> Checkable items appear only in submenus or context menus.

This is my understanding of it, however I am having a hard time finding a way around it. The Material Components `NavigationView` specifically [does different cases for these two types of menu's](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/NavigationMenuPresenter.java#L494-L524)

My current solution essentially re-implements a menu with normal views to achieve this. Is there any way to avoid this and just get the `SubMenu` to be selectable / checkable directly?

Answer (score 1):

The `Navigation Drawer` doesn't support selectable headers. But we can use a well-known library [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) to achieve this.

I will make the setup easier for you

**Dependencies:**

```
implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:7.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

Some of these dependencies you might already have in your project and you don't need to add them again

Just add this to `onCreate` of your `Activity` where you want to add the drawer

```
DrawerBuilder()
        .withActivity(this)
        .withToolbar(toolbar)
        .addDrawerItems(
            SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("New group"),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 1").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 2").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 3").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon),
            DividerDrawerItem(),
            SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("New group 2"),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 1").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 2").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon),
            PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Item 3").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon)
        )
        .build()
```

You can find lots of customization info [here](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#2-add-your-drawer) the [sample app](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app) in the repo is also contains lots of these customizations.

The result would be something like this

[image]