# How to access checkmark drawable in Android OS?

Tags: android, checkmark

I want to use Android OS drawables instead of providing my own.
How to access check mark icon?
I'm looking for check mark without rectagnle arround.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To access system provided resource, just access R.java file of Android.

for example:

```
android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background  // To access drawable resource
android.R.color.black      // To access color resources
android.R.dimen.colorstrip_height;   // To acess dimension resources
```

### Update:

If you are using Android 2.3 Gingerbread then you can access below in-built drawables:

1. btn_check_buttonless_off.png
   [image]
2. btn_check_buttonless_on.png
   [image]

Comment: checkbox_on_background have rectangle. I want clear check mark. Witjout rectangle.

Comment: Good one, thanks. I needed small rectangle checkboxes that fit in the OS version and these were right on. ?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple looks too big and awkward on a list