# Adding checkmark to a edittexted field

Tags: android, forms, password-confirmation

I am making a form in Android and I want to know how would I go insert a check mark when user enters both password correctly. I am going to use the built in drawable checkmark as described in this post ([How to access checkmark drawable in Android OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260049/how-to-access-checkmark-drawable-in-android-os))

```
//variables
     private EditText inputName, inputEmail, inputPassword, inputPasswordConfirm;
private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutEmail, inputLayoutPassword, inputLayoutConfirmPassword;
private Button btnNextSignUp; //button
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = ".{6,20}"; //regex expression for password validatoin
private Pattern patternToMatch;
private Matcher matcherToCheck;
private boolean  validatePassword(){

   String passwordString = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    //Check for if field is empty and password is valid meaning
    // it has to be greater than 6 characters
    if (passwordString.isEmpty() || !isPasswordValid(passwordString)){
        inputLayoutPassword.setError("Enter password greater than 6 characters");
        requestFocus(inputEmail);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        //set error layout to false if password has been filled with characters
        inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * helper method make sure password is greater than 6
 * @param passwordEntered for validation
 * @return true valid password, false invalid password
 */
private boolean isPasswordValid(String passwordEntered){

    patternToMatch = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
    matcherToCheck = patternToMatch.matcher(passwordEntered);
    return  matcherToCheck.matches();
}



 /**
    * isTwoPasswordsMatching
 * @param none
 * @returns returns confirmed password match
 * check the two passwords are equal to each other
 * */
private boolean isTwoPasswordsMatching(){
   //password field one
    String passwordString = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    //password field two confirm password field --> convert to string
      String passwordConfirmString = inputPasswordConfirm.getText().toString().trim();
    if (passwordString.equals(passwordConfirmString)){
        //field is valid add check mark or change underline field to green

    }
}

//get error to appear
private void requestFocus(View view){
    if (view.requestFocus()){             
     getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

[image: what I want to do]

Answer (score 1):

Try setCompoundDrawables

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.wen, null);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getMinimumWidth(),
drawable.getMinimumHeight());
edit.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

You can also use

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.drawableRight, 0);
```

For more, see [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: Hi I plan putting this feature into the method isTwoPasswordsMatching(), should I implentment this function in there?